# PHP "Cache-Control" header and Nginx

Tags: php, nginx, cache-control

Got php file:

```
<?
$maxAge = 2592000;
header ("Content-Type: application/x-javascript; charset=utf-8");
header ("Last-Modified: Thu, 19 Jul 2012 12:56:03 GMT");
header ("Expires: " . gmdate ('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', time () + $maxAge));
header ("Cache-Control: max-age=" . $maxAge);
```

Headers, when use local apache server

```
$curl -I http://localhost/js/js.php
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 16 Jul 2015 12:07:47 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.14 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l PHP/5.3.1 mod_apreq2-20090110/2.7.1 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.1
Last-Modified: Thu, 19 Jul 2012 12:56:03 GMT
Expires: Sat, 15 Aug 2015 12:07:47 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=2592000
Content-Type: application/x-javascript; charset=utf-8
```

When check on web (Nginx):

```
$ curl -I http://***/js/js.php
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 16 Jul 2015 12:15:21 GMT
Content-Type: application/x-javascript; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=10
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.8
Last-Modified: Thu, 19 Jul 2012 12:56:03 GMT
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

How can I enable Cache-Control from PHP headers?

Comment: It is possible that the php file is not interpreted because of the short open tag (<?). You can check the output with `curl -v http://localhost/js/js.php`.

Comment: "file is not interpreted" nope, it is interpretes fine

Comment: It works fine for me with the following configuration: http://pastebin.com/XFnkMDUu